# Need help installing a texture pack on Minecraft

Tags: 12.04, java, minecraft

So i need help installing a texture pack on minecraft. I don't know if this is the right site to ask but it has to do with ubuntu mostly. So every time I go on minecraft and "open texture pack folder" it gives me like a link on chrome to the file. I tried to put the texture pack in the browser but it didn't work. So now im trying to figure out how to find the .minecraft folder. 
Note: It says I'm not the owner of the laptop but I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.minecraft` folder on Ubuntu is located at `~/.minecraft` which, when expanded is `/home/username/.minecraft`. It is hidden, so you'll either have to open it with the terminal (`nautilus ~/.minecraft`) or by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> inside of `~/` (your Home directory) to show hidden files and folders. I'm not exactly sure why the button isn't working, but that's probably not really Ubuntu related.

Comment: Glad I could help ;). If this worked, would you mind marking it as the accepted answer (a check mark below the vote buttons)? @Khang